# C++ override virtual method throws an error "LNK2001: unresolved external symbol"

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qmake, qtgui

I'm developing C++ Qt application. I have one abstract class and two children. One of the children works exactly the way it should, but the second one causes an error:

> Freewer.obj:-1: Error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall Sierpinski::render(class QPainter &,class QRect)" (?render@Sierpinski@@UAEXAAVQPainter@@VQRect@@@Z)
>
> File not found: Freewer.obj

The problem is, that both of the children are defined the same way.
Let's show you my code.

Fractal.h:

```
#ifndef FRACTAL_H
#define FRACTAL_H

#include <QPainter>
#include <QRect>
#include <QDebug>

class Fractal
{
public:
    virtual void render(QPainter &painter, QRect target) = 0;
};

#endif // FRACTAL_H
```

Cantor.h:

```
#ifndef CANTOR_H
#define CANTOR_H

#include "Fractal.h"

class Cantor : public Fractal
{
public:
    void render(QPainter &painter, QRect target) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
};

#endif // CANTOR_H
```

Cantor.cpp:

```
#include "Cantor.h"

void Cantor::render(QPainter &painter, QRect target)
{
    Q_UNUSED(painter);
    Q_UNUSED(target);

    qDebug() << "Rendering Cantor's Discontinuum...";
}
```

Sierpinski.h:

```
#ifndef SIERPINSKI_H
#define SIERPINSKI_H

#include "Fractal.h"

class Sierpinski : public Fractal
{
public:
    void render(QPainter &painter, QRect target) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
};

#endif // SIERPINSKI_H
```

Sierpinski.cpp:

```
#include "Sierpinski.h"

void Sierpinski::render(QPainter &painter, QRect target)
{
    Q_UNUSED(painter);
    Q_UNUSED(target);

    qDebug() << "Rendering Sierpinski triangle...";
}
```

Now, when I want to create an instance of Cantor class, it works properly. But when I want to create an instance of Sierpinski class, it causes the error I wrote above.

When I change Sierpinsky header file this way:

Sierpinski.h:

```
#ifndef SIERPINSKI_H
#define SIERPINSKI_H

#include "Fractal.h"

class Sierpinski : public Fractal
{
public:
    void render(QPainter &painter, QRect target)
    {
        Q_UNUSED(painter);
        Q_UNUSED(target);

        qDebug() << "Rendering Sierpinski triangle...";
    }
};

#endif // SIERPINSKI_H
```

and I won't use Sierpinski.cpp, everything works properly. Isn't it weird? Can you help me please? Where do I have any mistake? I'd like to use Sierpinski definition the same way as Cantor's.

Thank you very much.

**Edit:**

After the question of *@Joachim Isaksson* I tried to add another one fractal the same way as Cantor and Sierpinski and I've got the same error as from Sierpinski. The new class is called Koch and it's not working. But when I leave Koch.cpp file out and I use definition of render function directly in header file, everything is ok.

Comment: Looks as if Sierpinski.cpp/Sierpinski.o wasn't linked. Are you sure you've not typo'd the name and the linker issues a warning about it?

Comment: Yeah, all file names and includes are generated by Qt Creator and I tried it more times. No warning issued.

Comment: Can you post the contents of the _.pro_ file, it looks that the _Sierpinski.cpp_ is not added to the project in _SOURCES_?

Comment: Or perhaps it was added, but since then you manually changed the file structure.  But @Zlatomir is surely correct, this is a problem with the .pro file.  Also be sure to clean/run qmake before rebuilding, out-of-date Makefiles (generated by qmake) can also do this.

Comment: @LaszloPapp it should run automatically, but it's a common problem that it doesn't, so Matt Phillips might be right about the file and _run qmake_ can fix the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are misusing the term "children". What you mean by that is subclasses. Children means something different in the Qt world.

The probable reason is that you do not have the corresponding source files in your `SOURCES` variable in your qmake project file.

Once you make that modiication, make sure qmake is rerun properly.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know. I used the "children" as "child classes" for OOP elements. And You, partially _@Zlatomir_ and _@Matt Phillips_ are right. My _.pro_ file content was correct, but it seems that makefiles were wrong. I'd manually run qmake before rebuilding and now everything works as it should. Thank you again. But now, I don't know whose answer should be marked as "the answer".

Comment: @elefantito: great, but there is just one answer, I updated my answer with that tip. Normally, qmake should rerun, but you seem to face a bug if you had followed the proper workflow. I personally even always do a clean in which case rerunning qmake is not necessary.